# CRM 2011: Plug-in - fetch statement, to inherit total sum from child entites

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I am looking to build a fairly simple plug in that calculates the amount of "units" used & remaining. I have two custom entites (Parent) bc_learninglicences & ( Child) bc_llbalance, the plug - in fires on create of bc_llbalance and another for update. 

 bc_llbalance: Contains
   
 bc_learninglicense (Look up field on parent entite bc_learninglicences / bc_name)
    
 bc_units (units that are used by this record)


bc_learninglicences: Contains 
  
  bc_name
  
  bc_unitsquantity (This is set to the total qty of units)
  
  bc_unitsused (this needs to inherit the sum of "bc_units" on "bc_llbalance")
   
 bc_unitsremaining ( simply bc_unitsquantity - bc_unitsused )

Ok so I have included the code I have just been trying to figure out how to get bc_unitsused to inherit the sum...

p.s I am new to developing for CRM 2011 with only a few weeks/ few projects experience.

```
// Obtain the execution context from the service provider.
Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext context (Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext) serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext));

//Extract the tracing service for use in debugging sandboxed plug-ins.
ITracingService tracingService =(ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));

if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
{
    // Obtain the target entity from the input parmameters.
    Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

    IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory =(IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
    IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

    EntityReference a = (EntityReference)entity.Attributes["bc_learninglicense"];// ((EntityReference)targetEntity.Attributes["bc_learninglicense"]).Id;

    if (entity.LogicalName == "bc_llbalance")
    {  
        //fetchxml to get the sum total of estimatedvalue
        string value_sum = string.Format(@"<fetch distinct='false' mapping='logical'
          aggregate='true'><entity name='bc_llbalance'><attribute name='bc_units'
          alias='units_sum' aggregate='sum' /><filter type='and'><condition
          attribute='bc_learninglicense' operator='eq' value='{0}' uiname=''</filter></entity>
          </fetch>", a.Id);

        FetchExpression fetch = new FetchExpression(value_sum);
        EntityCollection value_sum_result = service.RetrieveMultiple(fetch);
        decimal TotalValue = 0;
        // decimal TotalValue = 0;

        foreach (var c in value_sum_result.Entities)
        {
            TotalValue = ((Decimal)((AliasedValue)c["value_sum"]).Value);
        }
        Entity llc = new Entity("bc_learninglicences");
        llc.Id = a.Id;
        llc.Attributes["bc_unitsused"] = TotalValue;
        service.Update(llc);
    }
}
```

So i Think the issue lays with the connection to the parent 
entity "bc_learninglicences", "bc_learninglicense" is the look up field on the Child 
entity "bc_llbalance".


Hope this makes sense: Basically its not working 


i get this error from crm

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Unexpected exception from plug-in (Execute): LearningLicenses.LearningLicenses: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.Detail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
  <ErrorCode>-2147220956</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
  <Message>Unexpected exception from plug-in (Execute): LearningLicenses.LearningLicenses: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.</Message>
  <Timestamp>2013-01-24T13:11:51.2373399Z</Timestamp>
  <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
  <TraceText>

[LearningLicenses: LearningLicenses.LearningLicenses]
[c1b35170-c563-e211-8c6d-b499bafd5e5b: LearningLicenses.LearningLicenses: Create of bc_llbalance]


</TraceText>
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

Any advise or help with this solution would be greatfully appreciated.


Thanks for any time taken to aid me with this!

I also had some jscritp on load of parent form which calculates the sum from subgrid of children entities: This is just to clarify what i need to achieve... this is not sufficient as the parent form only updates on load where with plugin bc_learninglicences will be updated on create of bc_llbalance.

```
      function timeout(){
     setTimeout(calcUnitTotal, 3000);
    }

  function calcUnitTotal(){

   var grid = document.getElementById('Lines').control; 
   var ids = gridControl.get_allRecordIds();

   var sum = 0;
   var cellValue;

  for(i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {

     var cellValue = grid.get_selectedRecords('bc_units')[i].value;
     var number = Number(cellValue.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
     sum = sum + number;
                                                    }


   Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get('bc_unitsused').setValue(sum);

    var val1 = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('bc_unitsquantity').getValue(); 

    if(val1 != null && sum != null )
       {

    var result = val1 -  sum;

    Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get('bc_unitsremaining').setValue(result); 

     }
      else { alert(val1 + sum + "error: Values not passed for Remaining") }

     }
```

Comment: Can you refactor your catch block - you are hiding the actual error. Also if you aren't doing anything with the error info, why have a catch  block at all? edit: wait you have two catch blocks not doing anything. Basically, before we can help, we need the info from ex.Message (or remove the catch blocks and let the error be thrown)

Comment: Thanks. i have removed the try&catch & also changed "TotalValue" to decimal not string. this has given a new error which i have replaced the old error msg with in this post...

Comment: Ok i changed the last bit of code to <br>
 <br>llc.Attributes["bc_name"] = a.Id;
 <br>llc.Attributes["bc_unitsused"] = TotalValue;
<br>
    <br>                        service.Update(llc); <br> i have now got a new error --- <br> Unhandled Exception:  
  <ErrorCode>-2147220991</ErrorCode>
xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
  <Message>Invalid XML.</Message>
 <br> Any ideas? can also assume this is where it fails maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got this working here is the code hope it helps someone:

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        {


            // Obtain the execution context from the service provider.
            Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext context = (Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext)
                serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext));

            //Extract the tracing service for use in debugging sandboxed plug-ins.
            ITracingService tracingService =
                (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));

            IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

            if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") &&
                    context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
            {
            Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
                Guid a = ((EntityReference)entity["bc_learninglicense"]).Id;
                Entity llc = new Entity("bc_learninglicences");
                llc.Id = a;

                        //fetchxml to get the sum total of estimatedvalue
            string value_sum = string.Format(@"         
                <fetch distinct='false' mapping='logical' aggregate='true'> 
                    <entity name='bc_llbalance'>
                        <attribute name='bc_units' alias='units_sum' aggregate='sum' />
                           <filter type='and'>
                            <condition attribute='bc_learninglicense' operator='eq' value='{0}' uiname='' uitype='' />
                           </filter>
                    </entity>
                </fetch>", a);

                       EntityCollection value_sum_result = service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(value_sum));
                       decimal TotalValue = 0;
                       foreach (var c in value_sum_result.Entities)
                       {
                            TotalValue += ((Decimal)((AliasedValue)c["units_sum"]).Value);
                       }       
                        llc.Attributes["bc_unitsused"] = TotalValue;
                        service.Update(llc);
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: TotalValue = ((Decimal)((AliasedValue)c["units_sum"]).Value); should surely use '+=' otherwise the value is overwritten each time?

Comment: yes in this case im getting the sum/total figure so using the foreach (var c in value_sum_result.Entities)
it loops through each result and returns the sum.

Answer (score 0):

The error

```
The given key was not present in the dictionary
```

Means you are trying to retrieve a property that doesn't exist in the property bag.

I would guess this line is causing the exception:

```
TotalValue = ((Decimal)((AliasedValue)c["value_sum"]).Value);
```

Here you are assuming the value `value_sum` is present, but it may not be.

An easy way to test that, is to write something like:

```
if (c.Attributes.ContainsKey("value_sum"))
{
    throw new InvalidPluginException("Test - yep no key in the dictionary here!");
}
```

Once you can prove that this is causing the error, you then need to look at why that is the case.

Comment: Thanks, yeah i noticed that should be ... TotalValue = ((Decimal)((AliasedValue)c["units_sum"]).Value); i think, im now getting an error <Message>Invalid XML.</Message> Invalid XML " The XML passed to the platform is not well-formed XML ...

Comment: I also changed   llc.Id = a.Id;
to be llc.Attributes["bc_name"] = a.Id;

Comment: Is the field 'bc_name' a text field? If so, try = a.Id.ToString() (field types and assigned values should match)

Comment: yes basically bc_unitsused & bc_name exists on bc_learninglicences (the parent entity) & bc_learninglicense is a lookup field on bc_llbalance (Child entity) that looks up on (bc_learninglicences -bc_name)... confusing with the "licences" & "license" i didnt name the field/entity :p.  so for that bit of code im trying to set bc_unitsused to the total of all (bc_llbalance-bc_units) with the given bc_learninglicences(Parent). how would you suggest i structure that? thanks for you patients with this its much   appreciated.